# Return anonymous structure from expression macro

Tags: macros, haxe

Given a map Map<String, Int> how can I create anonymous structure from expression macro?

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
var res = myMacroFunc(["var1"=>12, "var2"=>66]);

res == {var1: 12, var2: 66}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a cleaner way to do this... but you can iterate through each expression in the array declaration, use switch statement to match `$a => $b` and generate [ObjectField](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/ObjectField.html). Store all ObjectFields in an array to create a EObjectDecl.

Here's a working version in [Haxe Playground](https://try.haxe.org/#3C976b24).

```
public static macro function myMacroFunc(e:haxe.macro.Expr):haxe.macro.Expr {
  final objects = [];
  switch (e.expr) {
    // input is array decl
    case EArrayDecl(values):
      {
        for (v in values) {
          switch (v) {
            // match expression of format $a => $b
            case macro $a => $b: {
                switch (a.expr) {
                  // "a" must be a string constant, so we extract that
                  case EConst(CString(s, _)): {
                      objects.push({field: s, expr: b});
                    }
                  case _: {}
                }
              }
            case _: {}
          }
        }
      }
    case _:
      {}
  }

  return {
    pos: e.pos, // re-use input position
    expr: EObjectDecl(objects) // pass to EObjectDecl
  };
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same if instead of passing map directly to the function, reference is used? final input = ["var1"=>12, "var2"=>66],  @Griffort?

Comment: @bh213 You can if you do use a normal, not-macro function. A macro function can only use the literal expressions passed since it executes at compile-time, so if you pass it "input", all it will know is you passed it a variable named "input". Is there a particular reason this needs to be a macro function?

Comment: I wanted to generate anon structure based on constant Map<String, String> that gets passed by reference. 
So:
var input = ["var1"=>12, "var2"=>66];
var ret = mapToStringMacro(input);
trace(ret) // {var1:12, var2:66}